# Helper Funcation Call Error - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to develop a simple login/logout web application in Rails4. I have following code for session helper

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

   # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
end
```

When I try to logout, it calls the controller function "forget" instead of helper function. Here is logout code for session controller class.

```
  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
      redirect_to root_url
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. Helpers got mixed into the view context, not the controller context, therefore the `forget` helper is not available in the controller. And even if it would, any method directly defined in the controller class will replace methods provided by included mixins.

Why don't you simply define the forget method in the controller itself? Do you need to use it elsewhere?

As a side note, the `forget` method you created in the controller will never work because you are calling `update_attribute` with no receiver hence the receiver will be the controller itself, whereas it should be the current user instance.

Your code is quite confusing. You may also want to read some Ruby/Rails book/course before trying to jump into building an application.

Comment: Actually I am following "Learn Web Development with Rails" by Michael Hartl. And it did the same thing. I don't know where I am doing wrong. 

Reference link: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out

Comment: It looks you are not reading the book carefully. https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-forgetting_users The forget method is implemented in the model, whereas you are adding it to a controller. There may be other errors in your code.